$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-n \sin x}\,dx $
Study the convergence of the sequence
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-n \sin x}\,dx $$ and find its limit.
My idea:
$I_n= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-n \sin x}\,dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} e^{-n \sin x}\,dx $.
Afterwards I did a change of variables in the second integral.
Let $y=\pi -x$. Then it becomes $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{n \sin y}\,dy$.
Now I am stuck.

Formatting: Use \sin x rather than sinx for the operator $\sin x$.

We have $$\int_{0}^{\pi}!{{\rm e}^{-n\sin \left( x \right) }},{\rm d}x=\pi,{
{\rm I}{0}\left(n\right)}-\pi,{{\rm \bf L}{0}\left(n\right)}$$ but our limit then has form $\infty - \infty$ and it is still tricky.

It's getting late and I can't think straight. Can you split it according to whether sine is larger or less than $1/\sqrt n$?

In the region in $[0,\pi]$ where $\sin y\geq \epsilon>0$, $e^{-n\sin x}$ converges uniformly to zero. But you can make the region where $\sin x \leq \epsilon$ small, and $e^{-n\sin x}$ is bounded, so you can make the integral small.

$\sin(\pi -x)=\sin x.$

The limit is equal $0.$

We have $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x.$ Thus $$I_n=2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}e^{-n\sin x}\,dx$$ As $\sin x\ge {2\over \pi} x$ we get $$I_n\le 2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}e^{-(2n/\pi)x}\,dx={\pi\over n}\left [1-e^{-n}\right ]\le {\pi\over n}\to 0$$
