Finding the limit of the sequence $I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-n \sin x} \mathrm{d}x $
Find the limit of the sequence $(I_n)_n$ where $I_n= \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-n \sin x}dx$.
I know that $\sin x\leq \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot x$ for every $x$ between $0$ and $\frac{\pi} {2}$. I think that the limit is $0$, but I have no idea how to reduce the integral.

Do you know DCT ? Notice that $\sin(x)\leq \frac{2}{\pi}$ is wrong...

this has already been asked

asked 15 days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4948802/1118406

Note that $$\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-n \sin x} \,dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-n \sin x} \,dx,$$
then you can use inequality
$$\sin x\geq \frac{2}{\pi}x, \quad x\in[0,\pi/2],$$
you can get
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-n \sin x} \,dx
\leq \int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-n\frac{2}{\pi}x} \,dx
=\frac{\pi(1-e^{-n})}{2n}\to0.$$

An other way :
Let $\varepsilon \in (0,\pi/2)$. You have that \begin{align*}
0\leq I_n&=\int_0^\varepsilon e^{-n\sin(x)}\,\mathrm d x+\int_\varepsilon ^{\pi-\varepsilon }e^{-n\sin(x)}\,\mathrm d x+\int_{\pi-\varepsilon }^\pi e^{-n\sin(x)}\,\mathrm d x\\
&=2\int_0^\varepsilon e^{-n\sin(x)}\,\mathrm d x+\underbrace{\int_\varepsilon ^{\pi-\varepsilon }e^{-n\sin(x)}\,\mathrm d x}_{=:I_n^\varepsilon }\\
&\leq 2\varepsilon + I_n^\varepsilon. 
\end{align*}
Since $\sin(x)>0$ for all $x\in[\varepsilon ,\pi-\varepsilon ]$, there is $C(\varepsilon )>0$ s.t. $\sin(x)\geq C(\varepsilon )$ for all $x\in [\varepsilon ,\pi-\varepsilon ]$. Therefore, $$e^{-n\sin(x)}\leq \frac{1}{nC(\varepsilon )},$$
for all $x\in [\varepsilon ,\pi-\varepsilon ]$, and thus $$0\leq I_n^\varepsilon \leq \frac{\pi-2\varepsilon }{C(\varepsilon )}\cdot \frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } 0.$$
Therefore, $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }|I_n|<2\varepsilon.$$
Since it's true for all $\varepsilon \in(0,\pi/2)$, you get that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }I_n=0.$$

Your idea is fantastic. Can it be applied on this integral $I_n= \int_{0}^{1}{arcsin (1-x^n) } \mathrm{d}x $?

@ale: The method is quite standard. To answer your question : try and see ;-)

Another, rather strange, solution yielding a smaller coefficient of $n^{-1}$ than the one obtained   by applying $\sin x\ge ({2/\pi})x,$ for $0\le x\le \pi/2.$
We have
$$I_n=2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}e^{-n\sin x}\,dx =
2\int\limits_0^{\pi/6}e^{-n\sin x}\,dx+2\int\limits_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}e^{-n\sin x}\,dx \\
\le {4\over \sqrt{3}}\int\limits_0^{\pi/6}e^{-n\sin x}\cos x\,dx +2\left ({\pi\over 2}-{\pi\over 6}\right )e^{-n/2}\\
={4\over n\sqrt{3} }\left (1-e^{-n/2}\right )+{2\pi\over 3}e^{-n/2}$$
The coefficient of $n^{-1}$ is equal $4/\sqrt{3}$ and is smaller than $\pi,$  the coefficient of $n^{-1}$ obtained by applying $\sin x\ge ({2/\pi})x,$ for $0\le x\le \pi/2.$
Remark Replacing $\pi/6$ by smaller angles we can get estimates of the form $(c+1)/n$ with an arbitrary positive constant $c.$
